# Rails 4 carrierwave and mysql can't convert nil into String

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have huge problem with upload images with carriervawe. i want to store my data inside images column in array.
Lets start from begining. I want to upload multiple images for post so i create migration :

```
class AddImagesToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :images, :text, array: true

  end
end
```

i have also my post images uploader:

```
class PostImagesUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  def root
    Rails.root.join 'public/'
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extensions_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

  storage :file
```

in my Post model i have

```
  mount_uploader :images, PostImagesUploader
```

in my view i have :

```
<%= form_for :post, html: { multipart: true } , url: create_post_path do |p| %>
<%= p.file_field :images,multiple: true %>
```

and finaly in my controller i have:

```
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:description,images: []) # { images: [] } also doesnt work
  end
```

and when i want to create my post (@post = Post.new(post_params)) i get this error :
**can't convert nil into String**

Please help
**EDITED**
What's more, if i remove multiple from field_text inside view and in controller i change params from {images: []} to :images everything is ok, but this is for single file.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have some unintentionally empty params in `post_params`.  Happens to all of us!

Try running this right before you create your post:
`puts post_params.to_s + "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"` or `puts post_params.inspect + "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"` or even `raise post_params.to_s`; it should give you some insights as to what values are missing when making your post.

The first two will output the strings to your web server console (the `%%%` signs are just so you can find the output in the noise), and the raise will interrupt your browsing and display it in-browser.  I'm happy to update this answer once you have more information.  If you find there is no output at all besides the `%%%` then your entire post_params variable is nil or empty.

Comment: Seems like there is no empty params
`{"description"=>"desc", "images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa4057f4 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20160902-22514-9svsmw>, @original_filename="aaaa.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[images][]\"; filename=\"aaa.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}`

Comment: Hi Juri, it looks like the `name` nested parameter is nil, which might be your problem.  You can see it in `post[images][]`.  If this helped at all, thanks for accepting/upvoting my answer.